# function to give out a percentage of readed files by person in R

Tags: r

I started to write this function:

```
owned.animal <- function(x){
  count.animals<- length(levels(x$animalsf))
  countowner<- 
  endcount <- tapply(countowner, junit20$animalsf, max)
  return(endcount)

}
```

Not yet working but i need a new help.

Its purpose is to get a dataframe with names of animals and owners which had this animal. It should give out a percentage of how many percent of animals a person has owned.

```
Example:

dog      max
dog      max
cat      tom
cat      max

output:
max      Tom
100      50
```

Is my thinking right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of unique animals each person has owned and divide it by total unique animals overall. This can be done with `tapply` as :

```
owned.animal <- function(df) {
  tapply(df[[1]], df[[2]], function(x) 
                  length(unique(x)))/length(unique(df[[1]])) * 100
}

owned.animal(df)
#max tom 
#100  50
```

---

In dplyr, you can count number of unique values with `n_distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(V2) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(V1)/n_distinct(df$V1) * 100)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("dog", "dog", "cat", "cat"), V2 = c("max", 
"max", "tom", "max")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Is it possible to tell me step by step, what`
```
owned.animal <- function(df) {
  tapply(df[[1]], df[[2]], function(x) 
                  length(unique(x)))/length(unique(df[[1]])) * 100
}
```
is doing.
I have a clue but some more detail would be great.

Comment: @Rnewbie for every person which is `df[[2]]`, we find number of unique animals where `animals` are in `df[[1]]` and number of unique animals is counted by `length(unique(x))` . You can get more details in `?tapply`.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(n = uniqueN(v1)/uniqueN(df$V1) * 100), V2]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
100 * rowMeans(table(df[2:1]) > 0)
# max tom 
#100  50
```